# How to make a frame in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I need to make an update to my website, and my webmaster has gone AWOL.  I'm totally unfamiliar with WordPress, and as technically proficient as I like to think of myself, I cannot find how to make a frame on a page that refers to another URL.  There are several other pages on my site that have similar frames, but the code for those pages appears to be totally empty.  What's the trick?

Requirement: page `my_page` needs to embed a frame that points at `http://mysite.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the page or post editor you need to switch to the `html tab` and insert code like this, at the point in the page it needs to appear:-

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" name="test" height="120" width="600">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>
```

Replace the value of `src` with the page you want to load and adjust `height` and `width` to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If the content are (WordPress Admin) for the similar pages are blank, your web person may have use a custom template. Look on the right side and see if a custom page template has been chosen.