# Content of frame in wordpress should not be full page rather just the action

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress, i need to create a frame from one page to another but the frame should not display the full page, but the action only, i.e., only the text boxes and labels, submit button 
to add a record into the designated table.

I created a frame using the help of the available guidance in stackoverflow from the link below:

[How to make a frame in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852705/how-to-make-a-frame-in-wordpress)

Now, the frame shows the full page, i.e., the admin dashboard, all menus, etc. 
In the src="", i have given the link to the page of add action. how to modify this to truncate the extra content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to hide the elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find('#header').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Klian.. but no alternative in php itself? I need to create the same in PHP... is it possible? of course, with the hide option as you suggested with jQuery.... Thanks..

Comment: echo '<a href="admin.php?page=mvc_geozone_rules-add"&type=imageTB_iframe=1&width=753&height=280&class="thickbox">Add New Geozone Rule</a>'; I used this code but frame is not created rather  full page is displayed.. any modification in this code you suggest?